# Using QueryableEntityCollectionView on EF6 Codefirst

Tags: wpf, telerik, ef-code-first, telerik-grid

I'm developing app using, WPF MVVMLight, and RadGridView (Telerik). 
I'm trying to bind

```
private readonly QueryableEntityCollectionView<Customer> _view;
this._view = new QueryableEntityCollectionView<Customer>(__,  "Customer");
```

but QueryableEntityCollectionView accept objectcontext only and I'm developing using EF6 Codefirst, I dont know how to use objectContext

Help Plz

Answer (score 3):

The ObjectContext can be retrieved from the DatabaseContext like this:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)myDatabaseContext).ObjectContext;
```